# How can changes to a Windows Forms ListBox control be made visible when in debug mode?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

It seems strange that Windows Forms controls are not visually updated during debug.

How can changes to Windows Forms ListBox controls be seen when debugging?

I have a Windows Forms ListBox in a VB .Net application. When I enter debug mode and step through any code which adds or removes items to the list, or changes which items are selected, such changes are not visible until execution resumes (F5).

I've confirmed the debugger is in Debug mode (not Release), and I've deleted everything in `..\Debug` and rebuilt, but these did not help. I searched here and Google, but found no results. I'm not sure I'm using the correct terminology.

Comment: You could simply add a watch for the box' Items property.

Comment: I would have to add watches for multiple collections, since I need to see a variety of graphical elements such as the items in the list and which items are selected/deselected during debug. Using watches for this would be cumbersome.